# React - Hooks, why is this implementation not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First of all I'm a newbie in all frontend-aspects, so please excuse that the answer to this questions is probably just, that I am dumb. However I have to implement a way that users can change their passwords.

There is already a useToken.js file, which looks like this:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function useToken() {
  // Checks storage for existing token.
  const getToken = () => {
    var tokenString = '';
    tokenString = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
    if (tokenString === null) {
      tokenString = localStorage.getItem('token');
    }
    const userToken = JSON.parse(tokenString);    
    return userToken?.token
  };

  const [token, setToken] = useState(getToken());

  const saveToken = userToken => {
    sessionStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(userToken));
    setToken(userToken.token);
  };

  return {
    setToken: saveToken,
    token
  }
}
```

So I tried creating a function, which uses the useToken function to send out the API- authentication credentials.

```
import React, {Component, useState} from 'react';
import useToken from '../security/useToken';

async function ChangeUserPassword(credentials){
  
    return fetch('https://api.testsite.de/change-password/', {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'JWT ' + useToken(),
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
            
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(credentials)
    })
    .then(data => data.json)
}

export default function ChangePassword(){
    const[old_password, setOldPassword] = useState();
    const[new_password, setNewPassword] = useState();

    const handleSubmit = async e =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        const creds = await ChangeUserPassword({
            old_password,
            new_password
        });
    }
```

The handleSubmit-function is called on a button press and the old_password and new_password from input fields.

When I try to run it, it gives me this an 'Unhandled Rejection Error', saying Hooks can only be called inside the body of a functional  Component. So I  changed the location of the useToken -call to inside the body of my function, but this give me exactly the same error.

```
async function ChangeUserPassword(credentials){
  const [token, setToken] = useState(useToken());
    return fetch('https://api.zvconnect.de/change-password/', {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'JWT ' + token,
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
            
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(credentials)
    })
    .then(data => data.json)
}
```

Comment: to use a `useX` hook, it needs to be either inside a component or *another function* named `useY`. In this case, `ChangeUserPassword` should be called `useChangeUserPassword`, then used within a component

Answer (score 0):

You can only use hooks inside components and other hooks, not inside a normal function.

You can't use it inside ChangeUserPassword()

Comment: why is  ChangeUserPassword() not a functional component? or does this mean only classes?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It is not a function that returns a Component (JSX)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your useState on the main component example:

```
const SampleApp = () => {
 const [state1, setState1] = useState;
 const [state2, setState2] = useState;

 const MyFunction1 = () => {
  .....
 }

 const MyFunction2 = () => {
  .....
 }

 return(
  <div></div>
 )
}

export default SampleApp;
```